# Why are my classes not found even though my imports are correct?

Tags: java

The [Classes ADSTool](http://www.mi.fh-wiesbaden.de/~barth/ads/info/adstooldoc/de/medieninf/ads/ADSTool.html) and the [Class PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) are not found by my compiler. I'm using Eclipse Helios. The docs say that I have to import `java.lang.Object` for both, and I imported `java.lang*`; I can't see why this isn't working.

Comment: We can't see why it's not working either without your code.

Comment: Please show your code (just a short but complete example) and the error you're getting.

Comment: are you sure the classes/jars are in your classpath ? where have you placed them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The docs say that I have to import java.lang.Object for both, and I imported java.lang*

Any documentation that tells you that you have to import classes in `java.lang` is blatantly wrong.  The classes in `java.lang` are implicitly imported.

---

In fact, I suspect that your problem is that you need to add the JAR files containing those two classes (ADSTool and PPM) to the build path of your Eclipse project.  If the classes are not available on the build path, the Eclipse compiler won't find them.

Comment: This worked out, I had to add JAR Files to my System Libraries. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

check Project->Properties->Java Build Path

did you include `JRE System Library` in Libraries Tab?

Answer (score 0):

Import `java.lang.*`, not `java.lang*`. The second dot matters; without it, the compiler can get confused about what you're actually trying to import.

Comment: A downvote, really? Importing `java.lang.*` may be unnecessary, but I guarantee you that importing `java.lang*` will cause an error. Just try it.